# C# automatically apply ToLower to method string parameter?

Tags: c#, tolower

Is there a way to make the C# compiler automatically apply ToLower() (or any other manipulating method invoke) to a particular method parameter before it gets used inside the method?

**//additional information**: its purpose is to use a Dictionary with a case-insensitive key. Apparently, my first approach was completely wrong as I've already found a totally different approach that addresses the Dictionary itself, not the key it is accessed with.

My bad! I should have provided you with that info. So, **no further answers needed**. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Better approach in this particular case: [c# Dictionary: making the Key case-insensitive through declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676245/c-sharp-dictionary-making-the-key-case-insensitive-through-declarations)

Comment: no, unless you write your own LoweredString class or you increase program complexity X10 to include aspects...

Comment: Could your provide your sample code?

Comment: could you elaborate more on what you are trying to do?

Comment: I don't know what your application is all about, but I think using `string` as `key` may be a flaw in your current design. Whenever we come up with any possible flaws, I always think it is a design flaw without having been properly tested. Distinct `key` needs to be checked, and it also takes time to retrieve the value via specific key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# Dictionary: making the Key case-insensitive through declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676245/c-sharp-dictionary-making-the-key-case-insensitive-through-declarations)

Comment: Maybe, but I came first. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the C# compiler will not do this for you (why should it be tailored to such a specific requirement?), but you *could* get this done by writing a simple wrapper `struct` around `string`:

```
struct LowerCaseString
{
    public LowerCaseString(string value)
    {
        this.value = value.ToLower();
    }

    private readonly string value;

    public static implicit operator LowerCaseString(string value)
    {
        return new LowerCaseString(value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value;
    }

    … // perhaps implement IEquatable<>, IComparable<>, etc.
}
```

The implicit conversion operator allows you to then write code like this:

```
Foo("Hello world.");

void Foo(LowerCaseString text)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

While this works as you would expect, there are some drawbacks with this approach:

- a tiny (possibly negligible) performance hit, since a wrapper object must be instantiated around your string.
- It might not be obvious to other users of your code that an implicit conversion operator exists, so they end up writing `new LowerCaseString("Hello world.")` instead. Looking at the class with Visual Studio's Object Browser would possibly resolve this issue if your team makes regular use of it.
- this wrapper does not allow you to specify the `CultureInfo` used for `.ToLower()`. Do you want to use the `CurrentCulture`, or `InvariantCulture`, or some other?

Comment: For my first kind of abstract question, this is a great approach. For my more specific need, however, there are better ways to achieve it. Anyway, I think, regarding the abstract question for a always-lowercase-string this is the best approach in my book. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Without using some sort of AOP, no.

[PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/aop.net) is one such tool, but it comes with added complexity, hidden code and much higher compile times.

It is much simpler to apply `ToLower` on the parameter directly *in* the method, or wrap all calls to the method with a method that would call `ToLower` beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Some AOP tools, like PostSharp, can do that.

But check twice that this is really what you want, and there is no easier and cleaner way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually looking for some cleaner and easier way... PostSharp is a little bit too heavy-weighted for this purpose, I guess.

Comment: Then give us some more details on what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You may have this done as suggested by others - trough AOP. However, this will get too complex and not worth the effort (in my opinion) if the case is only to pass lowercase strings.

You should provide more information on the matter, but I believe there are easier ways to achieve your goal. Take a look at the built-in string comparer classes - maybe `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` will suit your purpose, if you need lowercase strings for comparison. 
If you need to display the strings in lowercase format to the user, then this is a responsibility of the code that displays the strings, not the business logic.