# Case insensitive string for use in dictionary?

Tags: c#

I need a dictionary to have a key that is a string but ignores case. I've decompiled the Dictionary type and it basically creates a hash table of the key's hash code. I can't subclass string because its a primitive type so I've created my own class to use as a key:

```
struct StringCaseInsensitiveHash
{
    private readonly string _innerString;
    public StringCaseInsensitiveHash(string str)
    {
        _innerString = str;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(StringCaseInsensitiveHash stringCaseInsensitiveHash)
    {
        return stringCaseInsensitiveHash._innerString;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _innerString.ToLower().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this though?

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# Dictionary: making the Key case-insensitive through declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676245/c-sharp-dictionary-making-the-key-case-insensitive-through-declarations)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dictionary constructor allows you to pass `IEqualityComparer` which it will use to compare the keys and for hashing purpose too.

You can use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` , `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` or `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` depends upon your need.

More info available in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```